# Do not apply coupons if selected "Local Pickup"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use a code that adds a discount when choosing "Local Pickup" in the cart and at checkout.

```
/**
* Discount for Local Pickup
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_discount_for_pickup_shipping_method', 10, 1 );
function custom_discount_for_pickup_shipping_method( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 15; // Discount percentage

    $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
    $chosen_shipping_method    = explode(':', $chosen_shipping_method_id)[0];

    // Only for Local pickup chosen shipping method
    if ( strpos( $chosen_shipping_method_id, 'local_pickup' ) !== false ) {

        // Set variable
        $new_subtotal = 0;

        // Loop though each cart items and set prices in an array
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

            // Get product
            $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );

            // Product has no discount
            if ( ! $product->is_on_sale() ) {
                // line_subtotal
                $line_subtotal = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];

                // Add to new subtotal
                $new_subtotal += $line_subtotal;
            }
        }

        // Calculate the discount
        $discount = $new_subtotal * $percentage / 100;

        // Add the discount
        $cart->add_fee( __('Discount') . ' (' . $percentage . '%)', -$discount );
    }
}
```

I also created several coupons. How can I change this code to exclude all coupons from the calculation when I select "Local Pickup"?

How can you show a notice that coupons don't work when "Local Pickup" is selected?

I would be glad to have your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Add Percentage Discount to Local Pickup in Woocommerce
function local_pickup_discount($cart) {

    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
    $chosen_shipping_no_ajax = $chosen_methods[0];
    if (empty($applied_coupons)) {

        if (0 === strpos($chosen_shipping_no_ajax, 'local_pickup')) {
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.15; // Set your percentage. This here gives 15% discount
            $cart->add_fee(__('Discount added', 'yourtext-domain'), -$discount); // Change the text if needed
        }
    }

    if (0 === strpos($chosen_shipping_no_ajax, 'local_pickup') && !empty($applied_coupons)) {
        foreach ($applied_coupons as $key => $coupon) {
            WC()->cart->remove_coupon($coupon);
        }
        wc_add_notice(__('Coupon will not work for local pickup'), 'error');
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'local_pickup_discount');
```

**Tested OK** with **WooCommerce 6.4**

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I first select "Local Pickup" and then apply the coupon, it shows two notifications at once "Coupon code successfully added" and "Coupon will not work for local pickup". After that, shipping automatically changes to "Courier" (flat_rate). If I apply the coupon first, and then select "Local Pickup", then after the notification, shipping is still automatically changed to flat_rate.